# Comparaison of two graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a directed graph *G(V,E)* , i use DFS algorithm to get all the paths that has a given node *X* as a source. let call *G1(V,E)* the graph resulted from the DFS algorithm .

I want to know is there any way to recover the remaining nodes and edges of G that are not included in G1 . In other term,i want to  recover and stock the result of *G-G1* .

Thank you

Comment: You're going to have to be more explicit about how G1 is produced from G.

Comment: Its the result of the execution of the depth first search algorithm starting a given node X

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can recover the edges of G not used in G1, because it is always possible that G1 already contains all the edges that actually exist. Given G1, you can probably add edges to it that produce a plausible G, but both this G and the original G1 will produce the same graph if you run DFS on them again, so you can't tell which of them is the right answer.

More generally, you have a function which maps graphs with V vertices and E edges to graphs with V vertices and V-1 edges. A graph with E>V-1 edges will be mapped to one with V-1 edges. You can't tell which of the two was the original graph. In fact, for many values of V and E there will be more graphs with (V, E) vertices and edges than there are with (V, V-1) vertices and edges so you will have multiple graphs with (V, E) vertices and edges mapped to the same DFS tree, and you won't be able to tell which you started off with from the DFS tree.